# How to use Sort By desc by default with toggle link enabled?

Tags: 7, views

I am using [better exposed filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) and added `toggle link` sorting for a field. But the toggle link sort Asc order on first click. I want to make it Sort Desc on first click.

I tried to write :

```
MyField Desc|MyLabel
MyField Asc|MyLabel
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found any suitable way to do this. What I actually did, I changed the link using `jQuery`.